# Cast combobox SelectedValue to Enum type - WinForm

Tags: c#, enums, combobox

Hey guy's I wana cast combobox SelectedValue to Enum type, but selected value item is a list like {Title, Value}; ***Title* is "description attribute of enum items"** and ***Value* is "enum items"**.

```
var EnumItems = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Select(item =>
                   new
                   {
                       Text = item.GetEnumName(),
                       Value = item
                   }).ToList();
            MyCombo.DataSource = EnumItems;
            MyCombo.DisplayMember = "Text";
            MyCombo.ValueMember = "Value";
```

GetEnumName() Method:

```
public static string GetEnumName(this System.Enum myEnum)
        {
            var enumDisplayName = myEnum.GetType().GetMember(myEnum.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (enumDisplayName != null)
            {
                //return enumDisplayName.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Get();
                return string.Format("{0}", (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(myEnum.GetType().GetField(myEnum.ToString()), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute).Description, false);
            }

            return "";
        }
```

I try this way to cast:

```
var getEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), MyCombo.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

but this way return:

> **System.ArgumentException: 'Requested value '{ Text = enumDescriptionText, Value = enumValue }' was not found.'**

**Have you a solution for solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setting your data source, you creating **anonymous type** `'a` with `Text` and `Value` properties:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Select(item => new
{
    Text = item.GetEnumDescription(),
    Value = item
}).ToList();
```

so it is at result a `List<'a>`.

When you trying to retrieve selected in `ComboBox` value/item, it would be item of **anonymous type** `'a` too, so you can't cast it to `MyEnum` explicitly.

The **solution** may be in usage of `dynamic`s, which can be also of your anonymous type and at runtime has `Text` and `Value` properties:

```
private void OnComboBoxSelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic selectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        MyEnum enumItem = (MyEnum)selectedItem.Value;
        string itemDescription = selectedItem.Text;

        _ = MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Enum item: {0}\nItem description: {1}", enumItem, itemDescription));
    }
}
```

I have this result:

[image]

My enum looks like:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("My 1st item")]
    MyItem1,
    [Description("My 2nd item")]
    MyItem2,
    [Description("My 3rd item")]
    MyItem3
}
```

Mine `.GetEnumDescription()` is rewrited yours `.GetEnumName()` in ternary style:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum enumValue) =>
        enumValue.GetType().GetMember(nameof(enumValue)).FirstOrDefault() is MemberInfo
        ? $"{(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(enumValue.GetType().GetField(nameof(enumValue)), typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute)?.Description}"
        : string.Empty;
}
```